# dijit.form.checkboxes working like radio buttons but not changin UI component

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

For some reason my dojo checkboxes are not updating.

```
function booleanWidget(values, units, defaultValues)
{
var container, widget,onChangeFunction;
container = widgetContainer();
onChangeFunction = function (e)
{
    var orig, value, siblingCheckboxes, i, thisNodeCheckedStatus;
    orig = this.domNode.parentNode;
    // has correct value for component that checked or unchecked.
    thisNodeCheckedStatus = this.checked;
    siblingCheckboxes = dojo.query( "input[type=checkbox]",orig);



    for (i=0; i< siblingCheckboxes.length; i++)
    {
        if( this.id!=siblingCheckboxes[i].id )
        {
            // when I print out these console logs.  I see that I am always processing correct sibling.
            console.log("i="+i+" TARGET CONDITION="+!thisNodeCheckedStatus+" id="+siblingCheckboxes[i].id);
            console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"]="+siblingCheckboxes[i]);
            console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].checked="+siblingCheckboxes[i].checked);
            console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"checked\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("checked") );
            console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"value\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("value"));


// **** here*****  what do I need to do to get the checkbox to check or uncheck and display.  
// I can do any of the 3 commented out lines to try an update my checkboxes. see comment after line for result.  however sibling checkboxes does not remove check
//                siblingCheckboxes[i].checked = !thisNodeCheckedStatus; // changes .checked but not getAttribute.
//               siblingCheckboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", !thisNodeCheckedStatus); // changes : getAttribute() changes to false but not .checked
//                siblingCheckboxes[i].attr("checked", "!thisNodeCheckedStatus");  //receive : siblingCheckboxes[i].attr is not a function
            console.log("**siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].checked="+siblingCheckboxes[i].checked);
            console.log("**siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"checked\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("checked") );

        }
    }

    validForm();
}

widget = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
    name: 'value',
    value: 'Y',
    onChange: onChangeFunction
});
dojo.place(widget.domNode, container);
dojo.place("<span>true</span>", container);
if (!defaultValues || (defaultValues && defaultValues[0] === "Y")) {
    widget.attr("checked", true);
}

widget = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
    name: 'value',
    value: 'N',
    onChange: onChangeFunction
});
dojo.place(widget.domNode, container);
dojo.place("<span>false</span>", container);
if (defaultValues && defaultValues[1] === "N") {
    widget.attr("checked", true);
}

return container;
}
```

Comment: The templating system allows only one radio group per form? Fire (or fix) that templating system!

Comment: I would love to, but fixing/replacing the templating system in 48 hours.  not going to happen.  I have a release next week.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you, but why do you need two checkboxes or radiobuttons to let the user set a boolean value? A single checkbox does just that.

Comment: Originally we used radio buttons for all boolean sql conditions.  freemaker/struts2/struts json impl for this generic query page relies on all of the html elements names being "value".  Means all radio buttons part of same group. Jquerys solutions was to use checkboxes, and some adhoc scripting to xor checkbox selection.   I will post jquerys solution,   I nee to reproduce the jquery solution in dojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that you need to use set rather than attr. Try using:

```
widget.set('checked', true);
```

that should update the widget right away.

Comment: siblingCheckboxes[i].set("checked",false or true);  returns siblingCheckboxes[i].set is not a function... very odd.  The check boxes appear a row in a data grid.  I did find some reference of a reported bug with checkboxes not updating thier display when inside a data grid.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript snippet below lays down 2 checkboxes that I need to work like radio buttons. here is the generated html

```
<span class="valueField">
    <span>
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" wairole="presentation" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_0">
             <input id="dijit_form_CheckBox_0" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" type="checkbox" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" name="value" value="Y" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-pressed="true">
         </div>
         <span>true</span>
         <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox" wairole="presentation" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
              <input id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" type="checkbox" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" name="value" value="N" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" checked="false">
          </div>
           <span>false</span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

the console.log is showing that the attributes and .checked are changinging correctly, however the checkbox displayed in the browser is not updating.

I am using firefox 5.

```
function booleanWidget(values, units, defaultValues)
{
var container, widget,onChangeFunction;
container = widgetContainer();
onChangeFunction = function (e)
{
    var orig, value, siblingCheckboxes, i, thisNodeCheckedStatus;
    orig = this.domNode.parentNode;
    // has correct value for component that checked or unchecked.
    thisNodeCheckedStatus = this.checked;
    siblingCheckboxes = dojo.query( "input[type=checkbox]",orig);


    console.log("TARGET CONDITION="+!thisNodeCheckedStatus);



    for (i=0; i< siblingCheckboxes.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(siblingCheckboxes[i]);
        console.log(" id="+siblingCheckboxes[i].id+ "siblingCheckboxes["+i+"]="+siblingCheckboxes[i]);
        console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].checked="+siblingCheckboxes[i].checked);
        console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"checked\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("checked") );
        // console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].get(\"checked\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].get("checked") );         //siblingCheckboxes[i].get is not a function
        console.log("siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"value\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("value"));
        //
        if( this.id!=siblingCheckboxes[i].id )
        {
            console.log("targeting "+1);
            siblingCheckboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.attributes.isContentEditable=true;
            // when I print out these console logs.  I see that I am always processing correct sibling.


            siblingCheckboxes[i].checked = !thisNodeCheckedStatus; // changes .checked but not attribute.checked.
            siblingCheckboxes[i].setAttribute("checked", !thisNodeCheckedStatus); // changes attributes.checked but not .checked
            //                siblingCheckboxes[i].attr("checked", "!thisNodeCheckedStatus");  //gives me : siblingCheckboxes[i].attr is not a function
            //               siblingCheckboxes[i].set("checked",false);  //gives me : siblingCheckboxes[i].set is not a function


        }
        console.log("**siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].checked="+siblingCheckboxes[i].checked);
        console.log("**siblingCheckboxes["+i+"].getAttribute(\"checked\")="+siblingCheckboxes[i].getAttribute("checked") );
        console.log(siblingCheckboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode);
    }

    validForm();
}

widget = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
    name: 'value',
    value: 'Y',
    onChange: onChangeFunction
});
dojo.place(widget.domNode, container);
dojo.place("<span>true</span>", container);
if (!defaultValues || (defaultValues && defaultValues[0] === "Y")) {
    widget.attr("checked", true);
}

widget = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
    name: 'value',
    value: 'N',
    onChange: onChangeFunction
});
dojo.place(widget.domNode, container);
dojo.place("<span>false</span>", container);
if (defaultValues && defaultValues[1] === "N") {
    widget.attr("checked", true);
}

return container;
}
```

One of the developers remembers hearing about a reload, or refresh that is on span.  I tried surfing up the tree to the span nodes but I cannot find a refresh or reload method.  Any thought on how to tell the browser to refresh or reload the spans.